# Prove PB(8, {4,3}, 1) does not exist.

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I was reading Wallis, Intro to Combinatorial Design.

This is 2.1.3. I couldn't understand the way of counting. 
Hint says, let $f_4, f_3$ be the block counts of sizes 4,3 respectively, 
then,

$6f_4 + 3f_3 = 28$ a contradiction, 3 divides left but not right.

thanks in advance.

Notation: $PB(v, K, \lambda)$ v: number of vertices, K set of sizes of blocks, lambda: unique pair repetition count.

Comment: PB is pairwise balanced incomplete block design where size of the sets are allowed to be the member of the second parameter.

Comment: It would help if you wrote the entire exercise here. Most users who see this don't have Wallis' book on their shelves. Yet many of them could have helped you, as the trick is, as you figured out, not specific to material introduced in that book. Don't get me wrong. Naming your book **is** helpful context that answerer-wannabes appreciate (props for doing that). We just strongly prefer our questions to be as self-contained as possible. It is also to your benefit, because it makes the pool of people who can help you much, much larger.

Comment: Furthermore, I get the feeling that the exact description of the exercise would not be too long to be retyped here. No compex formulas either, so TeXification shouldn't prove to be a problem either (and can possibly avoided entirely).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'm sorry thats all. https://books.google.com/books?id=UILOBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=PB%288,+%7B4,3%7D,+1%29+wallis&source=bl&ots=83wneyvZeg&sig=vy2Muhch6ohkOHQlr9cULL-yTsc&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4VgiVfyuIsXGsAXSyIDQDw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=PB(8%2C%20%7B4%2C3%7D%2C%201)%20wallis&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

${4 \choose 2} = 6$, ${3 \choose 2} = 3$, ${8 \choose 2} = 28$.

Comment: Am I correct in guessing that the exercise is looking for a design with blocks of size three or four, on a set of eight, such that each pair of elements is contained in a unique block?

Comment: You are right. I could not be able to generalize this into a previous exercise on the same page. It asks $PB(v, \{k,3\}, 1) \implies k=2 (mod 3) \,where\, v=2\, (mod 3)$. I've been able to get to $k(k-1)f_k = 2 (mod 3)$.

Comment: Got it, $f_k=0 (mod3)$ is false. $f_k = 2 (mod 3)$ leads to $k(k-1)=1 (mod 3)$ again false. Therefore, $f_k = 1(mod 3)$. Rest is trivial.